# Оболтус - этимология

Tags: этимология

В русском языке много слов, обозначающий бездельника, лоботряса. Например, слово "оболтус". Интересно, какое у него происхождение?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это слово, не до конца понятное. 
Предположительно из диалектного слова, изначально означающего неряшливого, неопрятного человека, от "болтать". "Окончание" же (суффикс?) -ус связывают с подражанием латинскому.

*обо́лтус бо́лтус "болван", кашинск. (См.), также у Мельникова, 4, 361; оба́лтус "лодырь, дуралей", вятск. (Васн.). Ср. обалду́й. По мнению Соболевского (РФВ 66, 333; AfslPh 32, 627), образовано от болта́ть, -ся. Окончание -ус, согласно Преобр. (I, 630), представляет собой шутливое подражание лат. окончаниям (stupidus, stultus "глупый") в школьном жаргоне. Ср. сви́нтус.*
Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.

У это версии есть недостаток, заключающийся в том, что исходное слово и подражательное "окончание" - из разных языковых и культурных сред.   
В связи с этим в качестве версии можно принять и какую-то связь с обалдуем - словом видимо связанном с "балда" (дурак, глупец) фонетически сходным, но более распространенным, хотя и просторечным.   
Появление "оболтуя" из "обалдуя" моим представлением не противоречит, а "ус" - искусственное, как и в основной (фасмеровской) версии.

Кстати, "балда" - тоже слово интересной этимологии. Изначально оно означало большой молот, инструмент неуклюжий и "глупый", от него - "набалдашник".  Так что последняя версия происхождения оболтуса получает некоторые дополнительные аргументы.

Answer (score 4):

Грамота.ру дает такое определение для оболтуса: глупый, неотёсанный человек; бездельник.

Но мне кажется, что это слово изначально, судя по его применению, имело несколько другое значение:  бездельник, лентяй, шалопай http://enc-dic.com/word/o/Oboltus-2016.html.

Также, может быть, разгильдяй. Если считать, что "болтусъ — враль, болтунъ (семин.),  а слово "разгильдяй" происходит от "гильдия"(исключенных из гильдии, не входящих в эти сословные объединения называли разгильдяями, а их поведение – разгильдяйством), то оболтусы и разгильдяи чем-то похожи.

Они вовсе не глупые или неотесанные, а просто (по молодости лет) немного несерьезные, несобранные, безответственные. Много рассуждают (болтают), но мало занимаются действительно нужными, практическими делами

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю мнение Софии о том, что оболтус - это молодой пустослов, много болтающий и болтающийся без дела. Кстати, слово болтать имеет два значения: болтать что либо, например какую-то жидкость, и болтать о чём-либо, например о погоде. Интересно было бы понять, что из чего следует?